# How to add QT HTML String to CSS file?

Tags: html, css, qt

I have this code for printing my data. But I couldn't add html string to css. I need to add pdf document to css. Because html string so close to right side of paper.

```
 QString html=
           "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><b>"+json_map["Sample"].toString()+": </b><a>"+ui->sampleText->text()+"</a><br><b>"+json_map["Operator"].toString()+" : </b> <a>"+ui->operatorText->text()+"</a><br><b>"+json_map["Evalutaion"].toString()+" : </b> <a>"+ui->evalText->text()+" </a><br>"+
           "<b>"+json_map["Date"].toString()+" : </b> <a>"+ui->date->text()+"</a><br><br>"+
           "<b>"+json_map["Mixer"].toString()+" : </b> <a>300 </a>"+
           "<b>"+json_map["Moisture"].toString()+ ": </b> <a>"+ui->moistureText->text()+"</a><br>"+
           "<a>"+json_map["Consistency"].toString()+ ": </a><b></b><a>"+json_map["With"].toString()+" </a><a>"+ui->absorptionText->text()+"</a><br><br>"+
           "<b>"+json_map["Water500Fu"].toString()+" : </b> <a></a><br>"+
           "<b>"+json_map["Water14%"].toString()+" : </b> <a></a><br>"+
           "<b>"+json_map["DevelopmentTime"].toString()+" : </b> <a></a><br>"+
           "<b>"+json_map["Stability"].toString()+" : </b> <a></a><br>"+
           "<b>"+json_map["Softening10min"].toString()+" </b> <a></a><br>"+
           "<b>"+json_map["Softening12min"].toString()+" : </b><a></a><br>"+
           "<b>"+json_map["FQN"].toString()+" : </b> <a></a><br>"+
           "<b>"+json_map["Remarks"].toString()+" : </b><a>"+ui->remarkText->text()+"</a><br>"+
           "</body>"+
           "</html>";

   QTextDocument parent;
   parent.setHtml(html);
   QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
   printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
   printer.setColorMode(QPrinter::Color);
   printer.setOutputFileName(QDir::homePath()+"/Desktop/"+ui->operatorText->text());
   QPrintDialog *dlg = new QPrintDialog(&printer, this);
   dlg->setWindowTitle(QObject::tr("Bastak Test"));

   if(dlg->exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {

       QPainter painter(&printer);
       painter.drawPixmap(500, 5500, QPixmap(ui->qcustom->toPixmap(800,500,10.0)));
       parent.setDefaultFont(QFont("Times", 200));
       parent.drawContents(&painter);
       painter.end();
       //formula.savejson(printer.outputFileName());

    }
   delete dlg;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some difficulties to understand your question, so I make a few assumptions and wait for your reply:

- You want to generate a PDF from HTML,
- You need to apply CSS to the HTML

So to test it, I did the following minimum example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextDocument>
#include <QDir>
#include <QPrintDialog>
#include <QPainter>

int main( int argn, char **argc)
{
    QApplication app(argn, argc);
    QString html="<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style='color: blue;'>Hello World!</body></html>";

    QTextDocument parent;
    parent.setHtml(html);
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.setColorMode(QPrinter::Color);
    printer.setOutputFileName("test.pdf");

    QPainter painter(&printer);
    parent.setDefaultFont(QFont("Times", 200));
    parent.drawContents(&painter);
    painter.end();

   return 0;
}
```

I get the following result:

[image]

Comment: I got my answer thank you for helping. sorry for my lang. :)